# Should members be encouraged to check questions that have an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, answered-questions

If a question has a chosen answer, then should we encourage potential answerers to still go over them?

Commonly, such questions are left altogether. Sometimes, even the question isn't read if it has an answer.

If we can encourage people to still go over them, then they can provide helpful edits, or even new answers which are more comprehensive or which enhance the comprehension of existing questions.

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve here? That questions that have an answer on them already aren't receiving enough attention? If that is a problem, why is it a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions that already have an answer get viewed all the time, mainly by other people that have a similar issue that the question stated. Sometimes, these people may even be able to provide a more in depth answer after getting their problem fixed.

In general though, if a question already has an accepted answer, and you think that there could be a better answer provided; then just start a bounty on it.

There is a bounty reason for this :

***Improve Details*** *The current answers do not contain enough detail*.

Comment: Although I didn't mean those people who look at the question because they have the same problem and just meant that potential answerers usually skip answered questions, your answer quite shows me where is my query wrong. Thanks.